# pass Business Layer to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I have a WCF service and i am trying to write unit test cases for that. I am calling Business Layer and some other WCF service from one of the methods in that service. I am already using IcO pattern for my Business Layer. but in order to use Mock object of my Business Layer and WCF service here, i need to pass it at the time of creating that service instance. If i change my default constructor to accept it as a parameter, i will have to expose them to the service consumers.

if i change the constructor of the service, it will look like this:

```
public MyService(MyBusinessLayer bl, SomeWCFService otherSrvc)
{

}
```

Is it OK to do so? Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Send an interface of the service instead of an impementation. That way you can swap out the implementation at runtime with your mock.

Comment: Correct. I can do that. And i can do the same for my BL. But is it OK to do so? Will that not give "too much information" to the client? May be it violates Encapsulation principal as well. Isnt it?

Comment: In one system we created 2 constructors, one with parameters used by tests, and one without parameters that was used by the production code. This worked well, but not everyone on the team thought it was a good idea, since the tests use a different constructor. This is a case of choosing between two evils :)

Comment: Even if i do that, client config will expose them as a contract and it will not be under my control to ask consumers not to use parameterised constructor. Stuck here :(